# Bloquear Visualização Arquivo TFS

Tags: .net, visual-studio, team-foundation-server

Olá,

Tenho o seguinte problema.
Estou trabalhando com uma equipe através do TFS e compartilhei o projeto para que possam fazer o pull (Map & Get). Porém tem um arquivo específico que não quero que os demais desenvolvedores tenham acesso, pois tem informações sensíveis e privilegiadas. É possível configurar esse arquivo de tal modo que os outros membros do projeto TFS consigam fazer o pull dele, mas não consigam ler e acessá-lo?

Se sim, por favor, me ajudem.
Grato!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No TFS (Team Foundation Server), hoje conhecido como Azure DevOps Server desde a versão 2019, temos dois tipos de repositórios de código: Git, recomendado nos dias atuais como padrão pela Microsoft, e o TFVC (Team Foundation Version Control).

No TFVC você pode travar a edição do arquivo, ou no caso de o conteúdo ser sensível nem isso o desenvolvedor veria.

**Travar a edição**

- Check-in lock

O lock do check-in é menos restritivo, permitindo a visualização e o dev ter o arquivo na máquina, mas não podendo alterá-lo. A vantagem é que se for um arquivo de configuração você não precisa de outra estratégia para rodar a aplicação na máquina, pois localmente será possivel editá-lo, porém não poderá ser feito o check-in.
Essa opção está disponível clicando com o botão direito do mouse no arquivo, no menu de contexto escolha *Advanced* (1), e *Lock* (2), conforme imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Será aberta uma janela de dialogo com a relação dos arquivos que serão travados, é só confirmar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para desfazer o lock é só fazer o inverso.

- Check-out lock

A partir do TFS 2012, o travamento do check-out locks não tem um bom funcionamento por causa do [workspace local](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/decide-between-using-local-server-workspace?view=azure-devops).

**Travar a visualização**

O TFVC é um modelo de repositório CVCS (Centralized Version Control System ou Sistema de Controle de Versão Centralizado), diferentemente do [Git](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git) que é um [DVCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_version_control#Work_model) (Distributed Version Control System ou Sistema de Controle de Versão Distribuído), a diferença está descrita aqui: [Distributed Vs Centralized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_version_control#Distributed_vs._centralized); e por isso é possível controlar até mesmo a visualização ao arquivo:

No Source Control Explorer do Visual Studio, clique com o botão direito do mouse no arquivo, e no menu de contexto Advanced (2), e depois Security (3), conforme imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A janela que será aberta é a mesma do portal ou site, daí é só escolher o grupo ou usuário (1) e negar a permissão de *Read* (2), conforme imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Outras técnicas**

A técnica de obfuscação acima é bem ruim, pois o arquivo está no repositório, e qualquer erro no permissionamento ou administração de usuários pode expor o conteúdo. Se o objetivo for colocar URL's de serviços ou senha de banco de dados, o melhor é fazer isso no seu processo de CI/CD, ou seja, no seu pipeline, você terá ferramentas melhores e mais segurança. Se quiser saber mais sobre isso, procure por Azure Pipeline, ou abra uma nova pergunta.

Comment: Agradeço a resposta @egomesbrandao eu estive vendo as alternativas e preferi criar um projeto a parte com as classes que possuem códigos sensíveis e gerei uma DLL, assim o arquivo é referenciado e o código fica oculto. Acha que é uma boa ideia?

Comment: Você pode dar um exemplo melhor sobre o que você está querendo esconder no código?

Comment: As funções e variáveis declaradas